# Why haxelib does not find installed libraries?

Tags: haxe, haxelib

At ubuntu, If I do:

```
$ haxelib config
```

I get:

```
/home/suhaib/haxelib/
```

which has those libraries installed:

```
actuate  haxelib  random
```

however, if I tried to compile the project, I get error, as:

> $ haxe schoolbus.hxml  Error: Error: Library Random is not installed :
>   run 'haxelib install  Random'

although `random` is already installed.
Any idea?

Comment: random or Random?

Comment: Thanks! only few days we've wasted for this!!

Comment: I had this when I moved my haxelib folder form fat32 to ext4, the latter is case sensitive fs, so all of the sudden every module has to be entered in hxml with correct casing